# alarmManager setRepeating every Monday, every 1st of every month and 1st of January Android

Tags: android, date, alarmmanager

I do a function for setRepeating every Monday, every 1st of month and 1st of january , I do this for every Monday:

```
 GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(); 
while( date.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) != Calendar.MONDAY )
     date.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );
}
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingintentResetAlarms);
```

My problem is that I don't know how I can do for every 1st of every month and 1st of January because every month has different numbers of days.
I need ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by something like following and set the alarm every 365 days:

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
date.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingintentResetAlarms);

date.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingintentResetAlarms);
...
```

However there is a question about having 365 days or 366 days a year. Well another solution is maybe to avoid that and do something like:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingintentResetAlarms);
```

it triggers the alarm every day and in your broadcast receiver, you can check the current day:

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
if(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1)
   ....
```

Actually I think the second solution is better and more robust

Comment: thanks for you idea, but for the second solution, how you configure date for setRepeating in date.getTimeInmillis()? whit date.set.... ???

Comment: @elvega you can use System.currentTimeMillis() to get to current time instead

Comment: and for check if is monday or 1st of january is ??? I did this:                 if(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.MONDAY)  or                 if(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)==1 && date.get(Calendar.MONTH)==Calendar.JANUARY). ii's ok?

Comment: @elvega if(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.MONDAY) || (date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)==1 && date.get(Calendar.MONTH)==Calendar.JANUARY)

Comment: The alarm still does not work me . My intention is to reset certain values ​​of the database every Monday , so the receiver I put an update and put the values ​​I want to zero, but it does not work ....

Comment: @elvega The receiver doesn't get called or there is a problem with database?

Comment: I do not know exactly , this is my code for setting alarm and receiver :

Comment: Intent        intent  = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        //intent.putExtra("ReseteaBBDD", true);

        PendingIntent pendingintentResetAlarms = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingintentResetAlarms);
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingintentResetAlarms);

Comment: the receiver is down y the next answer

Comment: @elvega It looks like ok to me here. Have you defined your receiver in manifest?

Comment: I haven't defined my receiver, how could I do it?

Comment: @elvega Check here for tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm

Comment: I have followed the tutorial but I  had a problem:                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.actua.actuaconsultores.actuamindfulness.AlarmReceiver is not accessible from class android.app.ActivityThread
and I defined my receiver : <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: @elvega what is the problem?

Comment: I have followed the tutorial but I had a problem: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.actua.actuaconsultores.actuamindfulness.AlarmReceiver is not accessible from class android.app.ActivityThread and I defined my receiver : <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"> </action> </intent-filter> </receiver>

Comment: @elvega that was just an example, you should replace the intent-filter with your intent like com.example.android.myreceiver

Comment: the package name of app? my package is com.actua.actuaconsultores.actuamindfulness and the receiver is AlarmReceiver , so I replace android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED for com.actua.actuaconsultores.actuamindfulness.AlarmReceiver ???

Comment: @elvega it is up to you, if you set "something" in the intent-filter you need to also set intent.setAction("something") in your code

Comment: I have added : public void broadcastIntent(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
        intent.putExtra("ReseteaBBDD",true);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
PendingIntent pendingintentResetAlarms= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager manager=(AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.cancel(pendingintentResetAlarms);
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingintentResetAlarms);}

Comment: the error has disappeared but still not change the values ​​of the database

Comment: @elvega try to post a new question regarding your current problem

Comment: okk thanks this is the new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752241/alarmmanager-android-for-change-values-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

the receiver:

```
 final BasedeDatos bd = new BasedeDatos(context, "DBSesiones", null, 1);//parametros:contexto,nombre base de datos,
SQLiteDatabase db = bd.getWritableDatabase();


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        boolean bRestAlarms = bundle.getBoolean("ReseteaBBDD", false);
        if (bRestAlarms) {
            //call your subbroutine here
            GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

            if(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)==Calendar.MONDAY){
                //reseteo tabla semana
                for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
                    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + "SesionesSemana" + " SET " + columnas[i] + " = " + 0 + " WHERE " + "_id = 1");
                }
            } if(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1){//si es primero de mes
                //reseteo la tabla meses
                for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
                    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + "SesionesMes" + " SET " + columnas[i] + " = " + 0 + " WHERE " + "_id = 1");
                }
            }
            if(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)==1 && date.get(Calendar.MONTH)==Calendar.JANUARY){
                //reseteo la tabla años
                for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
                    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + "SesionesAno" + " SET " + columnas[i] + " = " + 0 + " WHERE " + "_id = 1");
                }
            }
            db.close();
        }
    }

}`
```

Comment: @Pooya this is my receiver